# Elpy cannot access Pydoc documentation for non-builtin packages

Tags: elpy, documentation

I am using Emacs 27.2 on up-to-date Fedora 34 and I installed Elpy from, as I recall, melpa. Python version (in `/usr/bin/python`) is 3.9.7. I am trying to use `C-c C-d` to access Python documentation. This works for built-in functions such as `print()`, but I cannot access any documentation for imported packages such as `numpy` this way. `pydoc numpy` works perfectly well in my terminal outside of Emacs, though.

The background process `elpy-rpc` is using the correct executable, but I have been unable to find any other relevant information as to why this is not working. I would prefer to use Pydoc rather than another package or system for documentation if possible, though I do not know how other systems (jedi?) work, so I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. And according to this post https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68627/how-to-automatically-enable-rst-mode-in-scipy-documentation-via-elpy, it can be solved. Could someone please share how. Thanks.

Comment: The linked question is also mine, apparently posted 2 days after this one. I apologize for having failed to track and post the solution here.