# How to automatically enable `rst-mode` in SciPy documentation via Elpy?

Tags: elpy

I am currently trying to make `Elpy` into my ideal Python IDE, and besides inline images in the console, I am mostly there (I don't need much).

`C-c C-d` (`M-x elpy-doc`) brings up documentation for the object at point when editing a `.py` file, and after some troubleshooting I have gotten this to work, mostly, for imported modules as well as built-in functions.
However, it turns out that `scipy` documentation is written in `ReST` and requires `rst-mode` for syntax highlighting.
**I want to automatically enable `rst-mode` whenever I open SciPy documentation via `elpy-doc`, or generally ReST documentation.** However, I cannot automate this because the buffer documentation is displayed in is not connected to a file. It does not seem possible to set any options related to `elpy-doc` to achieve such a thing.

Does this make sense, and if so, is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can advise `elpy-doc` to achieve this goal. This runs a function after elpy-doc to turn on rst-mode in the *Python Doc* buffer it creates, but only when the word scipy is in the buffer.

```
(defun turn-on-rst-mode ()
  (with-current-buffer "*Python Doc*"
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (search-forward "scipy")
      (rst-mode))))

(advice-add #'elpy-doc :after #'turn-on-rst-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks! Marked as answer. How would I go about adding other words to also achieve the same result? Purely out of curiosity, can you provide a regexp to the `(when (search-forward` line?

Comment: Search-forward looks for a string. Use re-search-forward if you want a regexp. Then you could match other patterns.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty keyboard macro called `pydoc-rst` bound to `C-x C-k 1` and `C-x C-k R` for this purpose:

```
(kmacro-lambda-form [?\C-c ?\C-d ?\C-x ?o ?\M-x ?r ?s ?t ?- ?m ?o ?d ?e return ?\C-x ?o] 0 "%d"))

(global-set-key [24 11 82] 'pydoc-rst)

(global-set-key [24 11 49] 'pydoc-rst)
```

Let me know if this seems wrong somehow.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the vector form of the keybindings? I'd write `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-k 1") 'pydoc-rst)`.

Comment: And since it's a toggle, I'd economize on keybindings and define just one of them.

Comment: @NickD I used `M-x insert-kbd-macro`, which provides keybindings in vector form when given a prefix argument. (Without a prefix argument, it only saves the macro by name.) This is the best method I have found for saving macros with keybindings so far. In retrospect I use `C-x C-k 1` more often so I would delete the other one if I knew which line referred to which keybinding.

Comment: Do `(string-to-vector (kbd "\C-x C-k 1"))` and you'll find out! Basically the integers in the vector are the ASCII codes of the characters in the string, so "1" <--> 49  and "R" <--> 82 (and  "C-x" <--> 24 and "C-k" <--> 11).